# Compare two passwd structures

Tags: c, linux, passwd

I have a problem which I have narrowed down as much as I can imagine. I want to count the lines in `/etc/passwd` two times. One time as a reference and one time to detect any change.

I initialize one `passwd` structure and count the number of entries in it. I then call `setpwent()`. After I have done that i initialize a second `passwd` struct, note that I have added a `sleep` call so it is enough time to add another user. Problem is that the new struct is identical to the first one even though I have added a new user and initialized a new struct after it has been added. So no difference.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        struct passwd *i;
        int y = 0;
        while((i = getpwent()) != NULL)
            y++;
        printf("Lines : %d\n", y);
        setpwent();
        sleep(30);
        struct passwd *j;
        int x = 0;
        while((j = getpwent()) != NULL)
            x++;
        printf("Lines : %d\n", x);
        setpwent();
    }
}
```

Comment: You *don't* initialize another struct, you just use another pointer variable what doesn't make a difference. You even *can't* initialize any kind of struct because there's no struct passed to `getpwent()`. Man pages are not quite clear but I woluld try calling `endpwent()` and not just `setpwent()` before the secound counting loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using `getpwent()`, which upon first call reads the `/etc/passwd` file and parses it internally, providing you all the entries. After that, when you do `setpwent()`, you are merely resetting an internal pointer that keeps track of ***already parsed*** entries. When you do `getpwent()` again after `setpwent()`, the `/etc/passwd` file will not be accessed a second time, as the information has already ben parsed.

If you want to force `getpwent()` to re-open and parse `/etc/passwd` every time, you should call `endpwent()` first. Replace the calls to `setpwent()` with `endpwent()` and you'll be good to go.

---

From [the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwent.3.html):

> The `setpwent()` function rewinds to the beginning of the password database.
>
> The `endpwent()` function is used to close the password database after all processing has been performed.